# Getting SMART info from HP P420i Contrller via a C# application

Tags: windows, command-line

We are trying to communicate with a hp server with a P420i controller via an application written in C#.We have used the "hpssacli" to retrieve SMART info.I was wondering if there is a set of library out there that we could interface to instead of working with command line interface. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Why are you only interested in getting the SMART info? SMART is not the only consideration that the HP Smart Array controllers factor into determining drive array health.

Comment: tnx for reply.we need to monitor the health status, and predict failure via an application. What are other ways to determine drive array health status?

Comment: What makes you think you can predict failure? Not every drive failure is predicted by SMART monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

- You could use the `hpssacli` utility to do what it's meant to do... Something like `hpssacli ctrl all show config`.
- Or configure the HP management agents to provide [email alerts](https://serverfault.com/questions/591307/email-notifications-about-hardware-raid-status/591319#591319) about the entire server's health.
- Maybe even set up the HP management agents to send SNMP alerts.
- You could leverage the HP Array Diagnostics Utility.
- You could parse the [HP Health Status Array](https://serverfault.com/questions/578248/hp-proliant-gen8-health-agents-and-el6-x-cpqhomibhealthstatusarray-has-changed) output.
- You could configure [Agent-less Management](http://h30507.www3.hp.com/t5/Coffee-Coaching-HP-and-Microsoft/HP-ProLiant-Gen8-Agentless-Management-Overview/ba-p/108579#.VBgde0vDvSw) and monitor the ILO4 instead of the OS.

Can you provide more context on why the C# application is necessary here?

Comment: tnx a lot.We have tried the hpssacli. the problem is we wanted it to be in XML format so it wont be necessasy to parse string. We also have tried **ctrl all diag file="" zip=on xml=on**. IT returns xml, but it is all the information for the controller.